# Branch git for a side project

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I am a git newbie so forgive my lack of knowledge but I am not even sure what questions to search google for.

I have a large project only I am working on being developed locally and pushed to a remote webserver with git.  The server has a post-receive hook which copies the files for serving with this command:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/my/remote/webserver/base/directory git checkout -f
```

This has been working fine for months.

Now, **I want to build a spinoff and run the new branch on my webserver**. I also want to be able to **switch back and forth between spinoff and master branches and overwrite the server's code** so that I can develop two separate websites simultaneously with only one server.  To start, I create a new git branch:

```
git checkout -b spinoff
```

I added a line and did a commit:

```
git commit -a -m 'test'
 [spinoff 51f90e9] test
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Now, I am trying to push to the remote branch. This does not work

```
git push origin master
 (everything up to date)
```

This command pushes as expected but does not copy the files over the web server

```
git push origin spinoff
```

Setting it up to push to the master doesn't seem to help:

```
git branch --set-upstream spinoff origin/master
```

[edited as pointed out by @Klas Mellbourn] That is the syntax for git 1.7.*. If you have git 1.8.*, the syntax is:

```
git branch -u origin spinoff
```

I know I am missing some **big key concept** here. My guess is that there are two remote repositories as expected but I need to set up something else to copy from the spinoff repo to the webserver.

I think I might have to edit the HEAD file in my remote repository? This currently contains:

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```

Comment: The complete solution for the benefit of other users. After you have your two branches:  
on remote:  
change your post-receive hook line to be `GIT_WORK_TREE=/my/remote/webserver/base/directory git checkout -f spinoff`  
on local:  
`git checkout spinoff`  
make any small change then do:  
`git commit -a -m 'message' && git push -u origin spinoff`  
To switch back to master, repeat all directions substituting 'spinoff' for 'master'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git push origin master` is giving the message up to date because you are trying to push the branch master, which you haven't changed.

Your hook is doing git `checkout -f`, which means it checks out HEAD. When you push spinoff to your repository, HEAD hasn't been changed (it points to master), so nothing is going to be updated.

You need to alter your hook to either look at what refs are being pushed, or designate a specific branch as the one which will get checked out.

Though git isn't very suited as a proper deployment tool see [this](http://gitolite.com/the-list-and-irc/deploy.html) list for different techniques.

Comment: This was my missing piece. I needed to change the line in my post-receive hook to: `GIT_WORK_TREE=/my/remote/webserver/base/directory git checkout -f sideproject`
There are probably better ways to do this as Ikke mentioned with his link but this is the quick and dirty

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of your commands seem a bit off to me.

This will push all your local branches that match remote branches to the server.

```
git push origin
```

This will push your local spinoff branch to the remote and make your local branch track the remote.

```
git push -u origin spinoff
```

This will set up the local branch spinoff to track the remote branch spinoff (which should not be needed if you did the previous command).

```
git branch -u origin spinoff
```

Comment: The syntax is off because I am currently stuck using git 1.7.*.  I tried your suggestions but the edited file is still not being copied onto the webserver.